# Show an icon for a get_user_meta

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

On my website I have a list of members and for each of them I display some info. One is the website URL. I would like to show the URL as an icon rather than the actual URL. The website address is dynamically populated by the

```
 $g_website = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'g_website', true );
                            if ( ! empty( $g_website ) ) {
                                ?>
                                <div><span class="label">Website: </span><?php echo esc_html( $g_website ); ?></div>
                                <?php
                            }
```

How can I add the icon here? I will remove the label as well and just show the icon. Thanks

Show the icon instead of the full URL

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Would be something like this (untested):

```php
$g_website = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'g_website', true );

if ( ! empty( $g_website ) ) {
    $website_icon_url = ''; // Set image icon URL.

    printf( 
        '<div><a href="%s"><img src="%s" /></a></div>',
        esc_url( $g_website, array( 'http', 'https' ) ),
        esc_url( $website_icon_url, array( 'http', 'https' ) )
    );
}
```